# Stepper motor powered but not turning

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, stepper, motordriver

Using a Raspberry Pi Pico and TMC 2208 driver to control a stepper motor I hear the coils but get no motion:

[image]

```
from machine import Pin
import utime

direction = Pin(14, Pin.OUT)
step = Pin(15, Pin.OUT)
enable = Pin(13, Pin.OUT)

enable.low()
direction.high()

def stepOne():
  step.high()
  utime.sleep(0.001)
  step.low()


while True:
    stepOne()
    utime.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: This question should be asked on raspberrypi.stackexchange.com people over there will be of more help.

Comment: try changing that .001 to a bigger number like 0.1.  if it works, try changing both 0.1 to smaller and smaller numbers... if it fails, you may want to get a multimeter to see what signals the pi is actually outputting.

Comment: I have already tried this suggestion